# Example of linearization for GIT

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Take a vector space $V$ (finite dimensional, over the complex numbers), let $G=SL(V)$. The group $G$ acts on $\mathbb{P}V$ and we can linearize its action to an action on the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$. This gives an action on $H^0(\mathbb{P}V,\mathcal{O}(1))$. My question is

as $G$-module, is $H^0(\mathbb{P}V,\mathcal{O}(1))$ isomorphic to $V$ or to  $V^{\vee}$?? and why??

Comment: The answer depends on your convention on what $\mathbb{P}V$ is --- it can be either the moduli space of 1-dimensional subspaces in $V$, or the moduli space of 1-dimensional quotient spaces. Both conventions are used, so it is better to specify what do you mean here.

Comment: I know, but I think the definition of \mathcal{O}(1) changes accordingly. Isn't it?? You should get in both cases the same answer

Comment: No! In the first case the answer is $V^\vee$, while in the second it is $V$.

Comment: So, it depends whether your define $\mathbb{P}V$ as $\Proj Sym(V)$ or $\Proj Sym(V^{\vee})$ ??

Comment: It is a bit confusing. $\mathbb{P}V$ and  $\mathbb{P}V^{\vee}$ are isomorphic; even as polarized varieties with polarization $\mathcal{O}(1)$. But they are NOT isomorphic as $SL(V)$-varieties?? (Moreover, $SL(V)$ does not have characters, so the linearization is unique)

Comment: When $\dim V > 2$ projective spaces ${\mathbb{P}}V$ and  ${\mathbb{P}}V^\vee$ are not isomorphisc (just because representations $V$ and $V^\vee$ are not isomorphic).

Comment: As varieties, they are both isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^n$. I think the group acting on $Proj \, Sym  \,V$ is $SL(V^{\vee})$ rather than $SL(V)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $\mathbb{P} V = \mathrm{Proj}\ \mathrm{Sym}(V^\vee)$. Quasi-coherent sheaves on the $\mathrm{Proj}$ are identified with graded modules over the graded ring (modulo torsion). Under this correspondence the sheaf $\mathcal{O}(1)$ goes to the graded module $\mathrm{Sym}(V^\vee)[1]$ (the ring shifted down by 1). The functor of global sections corresponds to taking the degree 0 part of the module, which is just $V^\vee$.

Answer (score 1):

The vector space $H^0(\mathbb{P}V,\mathcal{O}(1))$ can be identified with $V^{\vee}$. This is because elements of $H^0(\mathbb{P}V,\mathcal{O}(1))$ can be identified with linear functionals on $V$ (just think of the case where $V=\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, where $H^0(\mathbb{P}V,\mathcal{O}(1))$ is the collection of linear homogeneous polynomials on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$). The action of $\textrm{SL}(V)$ on $H^0(\mathbb{P}V,\mathcal{O}(1))$ is just the natural action on $V^{\vee}$.

More generally, the linearization on $\mathcal{O}(1)$ gives a linearization on $\mathcal{O}(d)$ for any $d$. We may identify $H^0(\mathbb{P}V,\mathcal{O}(d))$ with the symmetric power $S^d(V^{\vee})$ together with its natural action of $\textrm{SL}(V)$.